# “Sky with white clouds” and “white sky”

Tags: modifiers

If there is hot air in summer, we call it “hot summer.” Likewise, if there is white clouds in the sky, can we call it “white sky”?

“Forest is filled with green trees, so the forest is green.”

Comment: Please forgive me that it is not confined to English.

Comment: No. We say 'cloudy sky' if there are enough clouds to block the sun.

Comment: @wetcircuit Then, why is a place with cold air called “cold place”?

Comment: https://www.google.co.kr/amp/s/www.forbes.com/sites/marshallshepherd/2016/12/19/the-science-of-why-the-north-pole-is-cold/amp/ North Pole is cold = the place is cold

Comment: Start a new question if you want to debate the North Pole is called 'cold place' (it isn't). Thicker clouds are not white, they are grey, and the more they block the sun the darker the clouds. We say "cloudy sky", "grey sky", and "dark sky" to mean a daytime sky filled with clouds that block the sun. A 'white sky' would probably be understood as a bright haze or fog, not clouds.

Comment: Please edit your question to provide 1 or more complete sentences to establish a context for this phrase. It makes perfect sense, but that does not mean it will fit into a particular group of sentences.

Comment: @wetcircuit Yeah that’s what I say. the sky with grey clouds is called “grey sky.”

Comment: Can I ask about your native language.  I can't imagine that there is anything special about the use of adjectives in English that is not shared by other languages.  Certainly adjectives are used the same way to describe skies, places, seasons in the few European and asian languages that I have some familiarity with. I'm guessing Korea, from the google link you use.

Comment: @James K There are so many figurative words in Korean, and there are no rules about it, meanings depends on speakers, so it’s very complicated. Roughly saying, I can even say “eat food deliciously.”

Comment: @James K But it should be “eat delicious food.”

Comment: There are many figurative expressions in English too, and every other language.  Korean is just as complicated as English (and English is as complicated as Korean)  The rules are different:  English uses a copular verb "is" but the form of the adjective doesn't change (It is red. It was red) Korean adjectives conjugate for tense. But still, I think the question and answer is equally valid in Korean. A google image search for "white sky" and for "하얀 하늘" produces very similar results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A sky with some white cloud may also have blue between the clouds. Such a sky is not called a "white sky".  There is both blue and white in the sky

A sky completely covered with cloud appears grey. It can be called a grey sky.

The sky can appear to be white in conditions of haze or a covering of high cloud (cirrostratus) Such a sky can be called a "white sky" but such conditions are rare.

The adjective of colour describes the main or principle colour of an object. A "red dress" may have a small amount of other colours, but it would be mainly red.  There are special idioms for example a grey horse has white hair on dark skin; white man is actually has beige coloured skin. These idioms have to be learned separately.  Also the names of colours may not match your native languages. So "blue" can refer to both the light-blue and dark-blue. But "light red" is called "pink".

Similarly a season can be called hot if temperature is mainly high (or higher than typical). A place can be called cold if the temperature is mainly low in that place.  There is nothing special about English in this use of adjectives to describe seasons and places.